# Java Negative of a Number Instance

Tags: java, numbers, negative-number

I have a class like this:

```
public class SpiralGenerator<E extends Number> implements Iterator<List<E>> {
    private void generate(int pos, E... array) {
        if (pos == array.length) {
            List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
            currentResults.add(list);
            return;
        }
        generate(pos + 1, array);
        array[pos] = -array[pos];

    }
}
```

However it does not allow `array[pos] = -array[pos]`. If I use `Integer` instead of `E extends Number` it works fine.

Error message:

```
bad operand type E for unary operator '-'
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Number declared in class SpiralGenerator
```

Why does the current approach not work, and how could I solve it?

Comment: A BigDecimal is also a number but does not support unboxing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `Number` doesn't have any sort of "give me the negative value" operation - and that's what you want.

You could write your own method, which special-cased each kind of number you're interested in - but you can't just use the `-` operator. The method would be pretty ugly, and not provably type-safe. It may be all you've got though.

Answer (score 2):

With you code you rely on boxing/unboxing. This is not supported by all `Number` classes (e.g. `BigInteger`).

Therefore the compiler does not allow this.

Comment: No, this wouldn't be allowed even if `Number` only supported `Byte`, `Integer` and `Long` for example. There simply isn't a `-` operator supported for `Number`, and there's no *implicit* conversion from `Number` to any specific numeric type.

Comment: This is nonsense.  The problem is nothing to do with boxing / unboxing.  Besides, unboxing a `Number` is impossible because the compiler wouldn't know what type to unbox it to since `Number` is an abstract class.